# How to schedule API calls in a "for" loop with a counter?

Tags: python

I have a function with a `for` loop and inside the `for` loop, it pulls API data.
I would like to pause for an hour once the API calls reaches 450.
I have set up a counter and made another `if` statement but I'm not sure if this is right.

```
def master_function():
   test_data = sev_one_api_calls.get_all_catchpoint_tests()
   flat_getAll = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(test_data[key]) for key in test_data])
   
   count = 0
   concat_data = pd.DataFrame()
   for test_name, test_details in test_data.items():
       id = test_details.get('id') # pull id out of get_all_tests
       print(test_name, id)
       # feed in id to get_test_detail function.
       test_detailed_data = sev_one_api_calls.get_catchpoint_test_detail(id)

       # if id is in get_test_detail, flatten all id details and add it up.
       if test_detailed_data is not None:
           flat_detailed_data = json_to_dataframe(test_detailed_data)  # flatten id details into df
           # add up all results from test_detailed_data
           concat_data = pd.concat([concat_data, flat_detailed_data], ignore_index=True)
           # else if get_test_detail returns None, move on to the next id.
       else:
           continue

       count += 1
       if count >= 450:
           schedule.every().hour.do(master_function()) # wait for an hour and call again.
           while True:
               # Checks whether a scheduled task
               # is pending to run or not
               schedule.run_pending()
               time.sleep(1)

   combined = pd.merge(flat_getAll, concat_data, on='id', how='outer', left_index=True,
                     right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_remove'))

   # remove the duplicate columns
   combined.drop([i for i in combined.columns if 'remove' in i],
               axis=1, inplace=True)

   df = combined.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
   df.to_csv('../../data/COMBO.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: no i imported schedule

Comment: How would you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of testing this so there might be bugs.  But here is an example of one way you could alter your code to make it work.  This should at least give you an example of how the scheduler works and should point you in the right direction.

```
def master_function():
    test_data = sev_one_api_calls.get_all_catchpoint_tests()
    flat_getAll = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(test_data[key]) for key in test_data])
    concat_data = pd.DataFrame()
    schedule.every().hour.do(runloop,(test_data, concat_data))
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(0.1)  

def runloop(test_data, concat_data):
    count = 0
    for test_name, test_details in test_data.items():
        id = test_details.get('id') # pull id out of get_all_tests
        print(test_name, id)
        test_detailed_data = sev_one_api_calls.get_catchpoint_test_detail(id)
        if test_detailed_data is not None:
            flat_detailed_data = json_to_dataframe(test_detailed_data)  
            concat_data = pd.concat(
                [concat_data, flat_detailed_data], ignore_index=True
            )
            count += 1
        if count == 450:
            break
    combined = pd.merge(flat_getAll, concat_data, 
                        on='id', how='outer', left_index=True,
                        right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_remove'))
    combined.drop([i for i in combined.columns if 'remove' in i],
                   axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = combined.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
    df.to_csv('../../data/COMBO.csv', index=False)
      

master_function()
```